# Django with react deployment on google cloud vm

Tags: django, reactjs, linux, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework

Im trying to build server for my project where frontend is react and backend is django. I did it locally works just fine, but how I should deploy it on google cloud platform, i want to make it live through external ip of my virtual machine. I tried everything what i found on google, but usually all guides are for localhost.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read this link about how to create a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/get-started-bitnami-django), it's a tutorial to learn how to deploy an app in a compute engine with django, also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2dF3z7VuME) could help you.

With this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) you could learn how to add the firewall rules in case you require to open a specific port.
Just in case I leave you this [link](https://cloud.google.com/python/django), where you can learn how to deploy a django project in Google Cloud Platform with it's different products.

I hope this information is useful for you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Long time ago i deployed django app sucessfully on virtual machine, but how should i implement reactjs to it?

Comment: If you want to use compute engine, you have to configure the server by yourself or you could use appengine, I think could a better solution here is a link that you ccan follow to try it https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/deploying-react-app-to-google-app-engine-a6ea0d5af132

Comment: an this one for compute engine https://mziccard.me/2015/10/25/reactjs-google-compute-engine/, now it dependes on what you prefer

Comment: Thanks for help your links helped me to deploy my app and also this link was very helpful https://medium.com/@zackliutju/building-react-and-django-web-application-and-deploy-it-on-google-cloud-545f06eb5521